# Passwordless sudo works for one user, but not for another

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, sudoers

I struggle to create `passwordless sudo` for one user on my Debian server. I've added the following line to the `sudoers` file:

```
deployer ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

but it doesn't work.

To my surprise, I can easily create a new user

```
adduser deploy
passwd -l deploy
su deploy
touch somefile
```

add `deploy ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL` to `sudoers`, and

```
sudo cp somefile /etc/init.d/somefile
```

won't prompt me for a password.

Could you please explain what could be the difference between my existing user (deployer) and a new one (deploy), so that `passwordless sudo` would work for one, but not another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough info to make a 100% accurate response, but one possible cause would be that deployer is member of a group like e.g. wheel, which might get evaluated before the more specific rule you added later.

Comment: Thank you, @tink. It was the right guess. I ran `groups deployer` and saw that it belongs to two groups: "deployer" and "sudo". I removed the sudo group and now everything works as expected.